# How can I make two cells edit and display the same information in Numbers?

Tags: numbers

I would like two cells to contain the same information, if I modify one the other should modify also.

I was using the Concatenate function to make "slave" cells that pull data from a "source" cell but I have to travel back to the source cell and modify it there. Are there other ways to do this?

Comment: What is your original problem which solution would require 2 cells to be different and have the same value and at the same time being… different.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make 2 cells which content would be synchronised from each other.

To define b1=$a$1 and a1=$b$1 would create a loop of cross references.

This graph of dependency would be a cycle.

On the other hand you van make 2 cells depend on a common source:

a2=$a$1 and b2=$a$1.

This graph of dependency is a tree.